# Split function; discard all data before the last instance of a delimiter

Tags: vb.net

Okay so what I'm trying to do is get the filename from OpenFileDialog/SaveFileDialog, only without the full path, and dump said filename into a variable so I can use it for other things.

Using the Split function, I can get any part of the array between the delimiters ("\"), but what I'm trying to do is get all the information after the LAST delimiter in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to get the file name.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem very handily! My code now works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert this to a Fileinfo object and pull the name property?

([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx))

Comment: because I'm a noob and I didn't learn this stuff in class. :( this is what I get for picking a final project that requires stuff I haven't learned yet!